# I get "rsProcessingAborted" and "rsErrorExecutingCommand" randomly in my SQL Server Report builder report

Tags: sql-server, sql, postgresql, ssms

I have a report in which I get randomly the following error after pressing the "View Report" button (because in this report I need to select a parameter value from the dropdown field first):

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'my_very_special_dataset'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "My_linked_postgresql_server".
```

### My question is: What can be the cause of this error message?

**What I can exclude as a cause:** 
[Usually checking the permissions is stated as an advice](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/328c27d1-aa56-4613-9941-535b1b7574c4/query-execution-failed-for-dataset-rserrorexecutingcommand?forum=sqlreportingservices) or checking if the fields of a dataset still match the fields of that SQL View or table it uses.
But both can be excluded since it happens randomly. Also, the parameters cannot be the cause because with the very same parameters it can sometimes work and simtes give me that error.

**The enviroment in which the error occurs:** 
The error does only occur when opened via the browser in the Report Manager (of course the report was deployed there before) but NEVER occurred when opening the report with the "Run" functionality in the SQL Server Report builder.

**About the datasets:** 
The report's datasets use only views which I have defined on the server with the SQL Server Management studio, no tables or procedures or functions. However the views themself use functions and also gather information via OPENQUERY from a linked PostgreSQL server. None of the datasets use filters but use the parameter in the Where clause.

**Versions of the mentioned tools:** 
I use the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) version 13.0.16106.4 and SQL Server Report Builder version 3.0.

Comment: "For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors" so have you done this? What was the result? Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the hint! I have enabled remote errors and I have listed that remote error in my post above.

Comment: "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider" - You should verify you have the required OLE DB provider installed.  You should verify your syntax, which establishes the connection is correct also, there is a difference between "Data Source" and "DataSource".  This error can also sometimes be caused by a lack of permissions to the temporary file.

Comment: @Ramhound As I mentioned in my post, the error message occurs randomly. If the syntax would not be correct or the permissions would not suffice, then I would get the error message everytime, not just once in a while. I think rather that I fill the memory of the database too much. I noticed that it occurs after several executions which are done in rapid succession. Also, I removed a column which took a lot of runtime on the PostgreDB to get the values and the error occurs less often. I will see how it behaves in the next days.